# YAML: dictionary with empty value

Tags: dictionary, yaml

How do I write in YAML a dictionary (map) where one key has the empty string as its value?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
key:
```

is parsed as null -

```
%YAML 1.1
---
!!map {
    ? !!str "key"
    : !!null "null",
}
```

The correct answer is:

```
key: ""
```