# dictionary with empty key

Tags: dictionary, yaml

I would like to know if I can create a map in YAML with Empty KEY.

e.g. 
map{
somedifficultString: "someEasyString",
empty key: "none"
}

basically I would like to display "none" if the input key is "empty string"

Previous research:
1. YAML documentation does say use something  like ° for empty key?
http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#c-s-implicit-json-key%28c%29 
 I tried it, did not work
2. There is a answered question for how to do it for empty value and that is straightforward but not for empty key [YAML: dictionary with empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833927/yaml-dictionary-with-empty-value/836370#836370)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
"": none
```

and if you want `null` string then you can use `~:none`

Equivalent JSON

```
{
  "": "none"
}
```

Comment: I am using that bro... It works. please check official doc.

Comment: `~` indicates the `null` type (Python's `None`), which is not the same as an empty string (i.e. `''`)

Comment: According to YAML doc. you can use ~ for null

Answer (score -1):

Use the key indicator `?`:

```
{ somedifficultString: "someEasyString", ? : "none" }
```

You can also leave out the key alltogether:

```
{ somedifficultString: "someEasyString", : "none" }
```

Or if you want to be explicit, use quotes:

```
{ somedifficultString: "someEasyString", "": "none" }
```

Note that the third option has as subtly different interpretation, as quoting disallows YAML to guess the type, so you are guaranteed to end up with an empty string. The first two examples *may* be mapped by a YAML implementation to the [null type](http://yaml.org/type/null.html), so that you get a `null` value instead of an empty string. Consult the documentation of your YAML processor or just try it out.

The `°` in the YAML specification represents an empty scalar, not actual content, as defined [here](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786684).